# Implementing one to many relationship

Tags: sql, database

I'm new in programming. I'm designing a database that has two tables: Addresses and Customers. I don't know how to assign foreign keys. I don't know which way is better to use:

**Method1:**

Customer Table Columns:

CustomerID
FirstName
LastName
Address ID

Addresses Table Columns:

AddressId
Country
State
City
AddressLine

**Method2**

Customer Table:

CustomerId
FirstName
LastName

Addresses Table:

AddressId
CustomerId
Country
City
AddressLine

In other words I don't know where to place the foreign key.

Comment: you have to start by knowing which is one, and which is many in your relationship. Can one customer have many addresses? Can one address have many customers?

Comment: One customer can have many addresses, But One address can not have many customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to implement one to many, so the recommended way is to put the primary key for the table besides the one into the table of the many as a foreign key..

For example: if one costumer have many addresses and address have one costumer. so you will have to put the costumerId as a foreign key in the table of the address.

if one address can have many costumers and one costumer have one address. so you will have to put the AddressNumber as a foreign key in the table of the costumers.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

If each customer can have many addresses, then you want to use method 2 because then there can be multiple records in `Addresses` for each customer in `Customer`.

However, it seems to me like you might need a many-to-many relationship.  What happens if two customers share the same address?

You can accomplish this by including a third table, e.g. `CustomerAddresses` that logically sits in between `Customer` and `Addresses`.  This third table will hold the foreign keys from both of the other tables -- `CustomerID` and `AddressID`.

Comment: i think in most cases you'll want to create a separate address entry per customer, even if the address is the same, because when one customer edits his own address, you don't want it to change for any other customer. (but that really depends on what is being modeled)

Answer (score 0):

In your first method, one customer could only be associated to one address, as it has only one id referring to an address. But nothing prevents several customers from having the same address id. So this represent a `many-customer-to-one-address` relation. That's not what you want.

In your second method, the relation is reversed. Each address is associated to a customer, several addresses can be associated to the same customer, the is a `one-customer-to-many-addresses` relation.

In sql, to retrieve the addresses associated with a customer, you would do:

```
select * from address where customer_id = '<some customer_id>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I will point out that you **may** actually have a many to many relationship. One address can have more than one customer and one customer can have more than one address. In this case you use a Join table to model the relationship that contains the addressid and the customerid and nothing else. This would have a join PK of both those fields to ensure uniqueness.